# Is there a way to copy a Custom Property from one Bone to another ? Either on the same rig or across rigs

Tags: bones, custom-properties

I've seen this answered for objects but I see nothing when it comes to bones.
 I've played around and done some research, I'm wondering if it is even possible ? -Without having to write a python script.